# Как сверстать такую линию перед текстом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вырезать эти линии как картинки из макета или создать их собственноручно с помощью css?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через CSS никак. Можете SVG попробовать вставить

Comment: А если над слова использовать border-top: transparent и вместо стандартного фона поставить border-image с указанной картинкой с волной?

Comment: И будет вечно что-то обрезано. Вам при любом раскладе картинкой или блоком с фоном придется вставлять

Comment: Ну тут явно одинаковое (одно и то же) SVG изображение которое растягивается без сохранения пропорций на три разные ширины. Простейший вариант: из макета экспортируешь изображение в этом формате, вставляешь в HTML-разметку через `<img>` или копипастом содержимого, а затем через стили явно задаешь этим элементам значения `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачивайте картинку в svg. Далее код:

```css
.item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.item span {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./images/wawe.svg" alt="" style="width: 85%;">
    <span>85%</span>
  </div>
  <p>Приехали второй раз</p>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./images/wawe.svg" alt="" style="width: 95%;">
    <span>95%</span>
  </div>
  <p>Научились кататься</p>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./images/wawe.svg" alt="" style="width: 99%;">
    <span>99%</span>
  </div>
```